# Dealing with columns type List[int] in python-polars

Tags: list, optimization, group-by, apply, python-polars

Many times I find myself in a situation where I have a DataFrame and one column have the type of List[int].

For example, I have the following DF:

```py
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {"group": ["A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B"], 
     "value": [[3, 2, 5], [2,2,2], [2,5,9,4], [5,4,7,5,1], [9,4,5], [2,2]]}
)
```

Typically, Im using the `explode` and `groupby` methods in such situations. 
However, when dealing with numerous columns, the code can become somewhat 'dirtier'.

To address this, I thought to use the apply method:

```
(
    df
    .groupby('group')
    .agg(
        (pl.col('value').apply(lambda l: pl.concat(l)))
        )
    .with_columns(
        pl.col('value').apply(lambda l: pl.Series.median(l))
    )
)
```

Unfortunately, this approach sacrifices the parallelization benefits that Polars offers.
Also its execution is quite resource-costly. In cases where I have millions of rows, execution time can stretch from seconds to minutes.

Is there a better way to work with List[int]?
Is there a good way to optimize my code?

Comment: Is it not the same as `df.groupby('group').agg(pl.col('value').flatten().median())`?

Comment: Actually that seem to be exactly what I looked for… I couldn’t find it in the API

Comment: Ah okay. `Expr.flatten()` is an alias for `Expr.explode()` - it's just that the word "flatten" kind of makes more sense to read when used in an expression.